# How to send parameters to the java program on a server and get its response from and to the android device?

Tags: java, android, api, firebase, server

I have created a simple rule based "English-to-Marathi" translator in java using Eclipse which uses OpenNlp libraries & MySql database. Also, I have built an android chat application using Firebase. I want to translate the message before displaying it to the receiver, if the receiver's language is different than the sender's. What would be the easiest method for this?

Comment: Is your translator server based and reachable via internet?

Comment: Sounds like you want Firebase Cloud functions instead... It'll do translations using Google Translate

Comment: no, it is a normal eclipse java project, which takes an input from a user from console and displays the translated output.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to do that, but I would go for a more microservice approach, which would consist of have the Translation Service (you need to design an API as simple as: translateThis(string):string ) and the Chat application communication with it (you could use REST for example).

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am a beginner, so dnt knw much about creating API's and using them in android. Can you please give more explanatory ans or a link to some useful tutorial about this?

Comment: I am assuming this is on early stages (MVP probably). So, for your translation service you can use Vert.X. You can choose whom should request the translation: the client (android application) before sending/receiveing it to/from server; or the chat server (before sending the message to destination). I dont know if you already have your chat server designed, but you can use Vert.X as well. The communication between those players would be through a java client API.
Java client: http://square.github.io/retrofit/
Vetr.X http://tutorials.jenkov.com/vert.x/your-first-vertx-application.html